# Disable pull-to-refresh on InfiniteContainer in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Does anyone know if it is possible to disable the pull down to refresh functionality on codenameone's InfiniteContainer.

Maybe I am overlooking this in the API docs, but this shouldn't be to hard right?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nevermind. It finally occured to me that I should use the InfiniteScrollAdapter. The InfiniteContainer just wraps the InfiniteScrollAdapter and adds pull down to refresh.

Comment: Yes, it adds it inherently to the container and there is no way to disable that.